# mongodb reconfigure shard ports

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have restarted 2 shards on non standard ports, by chaning their .conf files. Now when I connect via mongo and issue a listshards I get:

```
mongos> db.runCommand( { listshards : 1 } );
Tue Oct 23 17:36:21 uncaught exception: error {
    "$err" : "error creating initial database config information :: caused by :: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for vserver-dev-2:37017",
    "code" : 11002
}
```

(37017 is the old port).
How can I update  the shard ports on the router (mongos) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Manual updating the ports on the mongo config server:

```
    mongo
    use config

    configsvr> db.shards.update({_id: "shard0000"} , {$set: {"host" : "vserver-dev-2:37018"}})
    configsvr> db.shards.find()
    { "_id" : "shard0000", "host" : "vserver-dev-2:37018" }
```

Comment: You are a savior! Thanks